# What's the right way to return from an AWS Lambda function in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS Lambda and there is one thing I find very confusing.

So far, I found following options how to return from a function in Node.js:

1.

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    context.succeed('ok');
}
```

2.

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    context.done(null, 'ok');
}
```

3.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, 'ok');
}
```

4.

```
exports.handler = async event => {
    return "ok";
}
```

How are these different? Any functionality or performance distinctions?

Can anyone explain how to terminate a function in the **right way**?

Comment: callback allows you to execute code with the current context of the handler.
return allows you to return a value which could be evaluated where you call the function from.
The two others ones, I'm not quite sure, so I would tell you to have a look to the documentation

Comment: @Izio My question was about what is the right way to go. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The answer is it depend on what you want to achieve

Comment: @Izio I just want to return a value from a Lambda function. I'm asking about best practices...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're probably using Node.js 8.10, which is so far the last Node.js version supported by AWS Lambda, otherwise the last (4.) snippet woudn't work at all (due to a syntax error).

In Node.js 8.10 all the above listed variants are valid, most of them are still there only for compatibility with earlier runtime versions.

The fist two (1. and 2.) are the oldest ones and it's not recomended to use them anymore. The `done(err?, res?)` function is an equivalent to the later added `callback(err?, res?)`, which was frequently used before Node.js 8.10 and you can still find a lot of code examples even in the official documentation. It's a typical callback and could be used in asynchronous processing:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        Bucket: "examplebucket", 
        Key: "HappyFace.jpg"
    };
    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, data);
    });    
}
```

Nevertheless, this function has all the drawbacks of using callbacks in general (Callback Hell).

Up Node.js 8.10 you can use Promises together with `async/await` syntactic sugar, which makes asynchronous computation look like synchronous. AWS JavaScript SDK added a function `promise()` to almost all the functions previously using callbacks. Now you can write:

```
exports.handler = async event => {
    var params = {
        Bucket: "examplebucket", 
        Key: "HappyFace.jpg"
    };
    var data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    // here you process the already resolved data...
    return data;

    // or you can omit `await` here whatsoever:
    // return s3.getObject(params).promise();
}
```

Which produces shorter and eleganter code, more readable for humans.

Of course, at the end you can choose what you like, just compare your example snippets...

Comment: Can you omit the await statement and simply return s3.getObject(params).promise()?

Comment: @rjobindon Yes, you can do it in this case, I just wanted to demonstrate the async/await usage. I will edit the example slightly.

Comment: @ttulka does this also work for lambda@edge?

Comment: Does what you return from a function important in any way? For example, if a lambda function is being used to process events from an SQS queue can the return value indicate to AWS that an event was not processed?

Comment: @fraxture Yes, you can. If you throw an error, that tells AWS that no messages were processed, or if you configure it you can return the failed messages: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#services-sqs-batchfailurereporting